# Angular Reactive Forms: Prevent value changes from executing in directive

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular project in which i am using reactive forms. I created a directive to apply some validation. Below is the directive

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[onlyNumber]'
})
export class NumberDirective{
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control: NgControl) {}

    @HostListener('change'['$event.target'])
    onChange() {
      if (isNan(+this.el.nativeElement.value)) {
         this.control.control.setErrors({invalidNumber:true}, {emitEvent:false});
        // Here i want to prevent valueChanges of this control from executing.
      }
    }
}
```

I will be using that directive in the following way

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input class="form-control" formControlName="amount" onlyNumber/>
</form>
```

How can i prevent the value changes from executing in a directive. Please help me in this. I have tried many ways, but it still executes the valueChanges for that.

Comment: You should use a custom `Validator` function instead of a `Directive` for this case.

Comment: Agree with @Shuvo, any reason why you are using `Directive`

Comment: Using a Directive is for Template driven Forms ( when we use `[(ngModel)]`, in ReactiveForms you use custom validators

Comment: The application which i work on has to support IE. In IE, if we declare an element with type as number, then it is accepting alphabets as well. For that purpose, i have created this directive. I tried using `Validator`, but in that i am not getting the correct value. For example if the value is 12abc, in validator i am getting as 12 and it considers it as a valid field. But user sees 12abc only

Comment: @YogendraR any idea on how to do??